# Can I flash linux on my phone?

Tags: linux, android, root

As a experiment I want to see if I can flash a custom rom of a light weight linux distro such as alpine. But before I risk potentialy bricking the phone I have for the experiment and turning it into a very expensive paper weight, I thought I'd ask here.

Phone for the experiment: Sony xperia z3

Linux distro: Alpine

Root acces? Yes

After that I would of used a heavier but still light weight linux distro, to see how far it'll go. Possibly debian unless I find something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As a experiment I want to see if I can flash a custom rom of a light weight linux distro

Yes, if

1. You have bootloader/recovery level access to the phone.  Root level is not enough, you need complete control of the flash from outside the OS to flash the image outside of a running operating system.  Phones are not like PCs and you can't "boot from USB."
2. You have an image created of this operating system ready to flash.  The flash may need to be "partitioned" in a certain format to work with the bootloader, or it may need to include the bootloader.
3. You configure the bootloader on this image to boot the kernel from the internal flash hardware.  This will require knowing how the phone's bootloader loads Linux, the initrd, and any other stuff.  This also may require building the MTD drivers into the kernel, and also you need the right drivers for the specific flash hardware in the phone.
4. You have Linux drivers to all of the phone hardware that matches the version of the kernel in your distro.  1 is also a big problem as phone manufacturers tend to lock down bootloaders.

4 is the big problem for everyone, as device manufactuers don't release the source code of drivers (which enables one to recomplie for the current kernel version) but binary only.

If all this is really new to you and you are looking for a good place to start, try flashing OpenWRT and then installing/using additional packages under it.  It will teach you how Linux works in an embedded environment like a phone.

Comment: Interesting suggestion in the last paragraph but I think it should have been mentioned that OpenWRT is typically for router-like devices, I never heard of it being installed in phones/tablets. Sure, router-like devices do share the same ARM hardware architecture but aren't really the same.

Comment: They're alike in that you are dealing with an OS being loaded from flash/MTD device and not typical PC architecture with UEFI.